# How to effectively open downloaded file in external application using expo linking

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-linking

I'm downloading a file from an URI, and trying to open it in another application. This file is a simple .xlsx spreadsheet. I'm using an Android device to test. In the code below is a reproduceble example:

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { Button, View } from 'react-native'
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'

const App = () => {
  const download = useCallback(async () => {
    const downloadUri = 'http://url.to/my/spreadsheet.xlsx')
    const localPath = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}spreadsheet.xlsx`
    try {
      await FileSystem.downladAsync(downloadUri, localPath)
        .then(async ({ uri }) => {
          const contentURL = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri)
          await Linking.openURL(contentURL)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={download}>
        Pree Me!
      </Button>
    </View>
  )
}
```

No error is displayed in the console log, however when the `Linking` is attempting to open the file gives the error "Google Sheets was unable to open your Spreadsheet". The same thing happens when I'm trying to open other filetypes as:

- `.docx` with Google Docs
- `.pptx` with Google Slides
- `.pdf`  with Drive
- ... and so on

Any idea what could be causing this?

***NOTE***

I verified if the file returned by the URL is not corrupted using:

`curl -X GET http://url.to/my/spreadsheet.xlsx -o spreadsheet.xlsx` (from within the device) and it could be opened normally with Google Sheets.

Comment: Maybe you need permissions in AndroidManifest.xml check the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-data-from-google-spreadsheet-in-android/) and [Manifest.permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Comment: I get a similar issue where I'm using Linking.openURL to open a local file with it's URI (file:///) but on clicking it no errors are logged but nothing happens. Strange.